# Matching case classes in scala: ~(a,b) match{case a~b=>...}

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I have a case class

```
case class ~[a,b](_1:a, _2:b)
```

When I want to do pattetn matching

```
new ~("a", 25) match{
  case "a" ~ 25 =>
}
```

I can use it this way because `"a" ~ 25` and `~("a", 25)` are equivalent. But if I want to match `new ~("a", new ~("b", 25))` by `{case "a" ~ "b" ~ 25 => }` troubles begin. I understand that this statements aren't equivalent. So, how  `new ~("a", new ~("b", 25))` can be presented? By what rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
new ~("a", new ~("b", 25)) match {
  case "a" ~ ("b" ~ 25) =>
}
```

So, you’ll have to put the parentheses the same way they are in the initial clause. Otherwise the tilde is left-associative, therefore the type of the pattern will be different and it won’t compile.

```
case "a" ~ "b" ~ 25
```

is the same as

```
case ("a" ~ "b") ~ 25
```

which would be wrong in your case.

**Appendix**

You can get right-associativity by having a colon as the last character in your class/method name. The following compiles and matches without parentheses (and you can drop the `new` as the compiler won’t be confused anymore by `$tilde$colon`):

```
case class ~:[a,b](_1:a, _2:b)

~:("a", ~:("b", 25)) match {
  case "a" ~: "b" ~: 25 =>
}
```

**Responses**

1) Without the `new` keyword, the `case class ~` is shadowed by `unary_~` which gives the bitwise negation of the argument. An expression like `~ 2` is internally evaluated to `unary_~(2)` and the same goes for the case of `~ ("a", 1)` – however unless you define `unary_~` on that tuple, this will give an error. With the `new` keyword you advise the compiler to explicitly look for a class with that name, so it won’t get confused. 
(Technically, you could work around this by using `$tilde("a", 1)` which is the internal name for your `case class ~`, but since this is a compiler detail, you should probably not rely on it.)

2&3) The right-associativity is referenced in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/198). Section ‘Infix Operations’

> The associativity of an operator is determined by the operator’s last character. Operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative. All other operators are left-associative.

By the way, right-associativity is the trick that allows for creating lists with `Nil`. (`Nil` is the empty `List` and has the right-associative concatenation operator `::` defined.)

```
val l: List[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

which is evaluated as follows

```
val l: List[Int] = (1 :: (2 :: (3 :: Nil)))
```

or, more precisely, since `3 :: Nil` ≡ `Nil.::(3)`, as

```
val l: List[Int] = ( ( Nil.::(3) ).::(2) ).::(1)
```

Comment: I don't understand

1)Why compiler is confused when class name is '~' and I don't put 'new' keyword?
2)>>You can get right-associativity by having a colon as the last character in your class/method name. 
That's creepy :3 Where can I read about this unobvious behavior?

Comment: You can already avoid new by using ~ like an infix operator, as done in the Scala parser combinator libraries. That is, `a ~ b` should work fine (not retested though).